# Hide opened drawer when clicking outside of the drawer

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, topcoat

I am using the following code to toggle (show/hide) a drawer:
http://outof.me/navigation-drawer-pattern-with-topcoat-css-library/

```
slideMenuButton.onclick = function (e) {
    var cl = document.body.classList;
    if (cl.contains('left-nav')) {
        cl.remove('left-nav');
    } else {
        cl.add('left-nav');
    }
};
```

Works fine. Now, I would like the drawer to close whenever *anything* outside the drawer is clicked. Is there a recommended way how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be:

```
$("body").on("click",function(e) {
    var cl = document.body.classList;
    if (cl.contains('left-nav')) {
        cl.remove('left-nav');
    }
}
```

(Works for me.)